# how to get selected value of p:column of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to get selected value of p:column of p:datatable by using javascript(jquery). Do you think is that possible ? I tried several ways but I could not succeed. Any help will be great.

Regards

Here is the sample Code :

```
<p:dataTable id="attachmentsTable" var="dataRow" value="#{taslakFaturaBean.attachments}" style="width:980px; text-align:center;">
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                #{dataRow.AttachID}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Dosya Tarihi">
                #{dataRow.AttachDate}
            </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Dosya">
                <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="İndir" icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s" rendered="#{not empty dataRow.AttachData}" ajax="false">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
```

I want to get selected p:column's AttachId when I click downloadLink commondButton by javascript.

Comment: could you give a bit more details what you want? part of the source code will be good

Comment: do you want something like this? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: your answers are great. But does not fit what I want. I need a javascript method which gives value of what the selected at p:column.I provided sample code.Please help me

Comment: do you mean that you need to get the dataSlected from the datatable if yes the link that provided by Daniyar is the best way to see how

Comment: yes Lagami. exactly . I want to do it by javascript :) Not by beans . I want to complete all the process on the frontend. I do not want to go to backend

Comment: I don't know the answer now, but as I understand it PrimeFaces has a JavaScript API for its components (but it might not be enough for your requirements). You can give your datatable a widgetVar property like widgetVar="MyTable". Then in JavaScript, you can get this object by calling PF("MyTable"). You can then use Firebug to see what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure javascript I think it can be by this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function test(attachId) {
            // get attachId
        }
</script>
```

and in your dataTable like this

```
<input type="button" onlcick="test(#{dataRow.AttachID});" value="GetID" />
```

if you want to use commandButton you can try to use onclick="test(#{dataRow.AttachID})" but not sure about that :)